# What happen when removing resources from terraform configuration file

Tags: terraform

I am trying to find my way in terraform , i am going through the documentation and got confused about what is exactly will happen if a resource has been deleted manually from the configuration file then we ran the apply command on the modified configuration file please ?
my understanding that the state file will still have the deleted resource as well it will still be actually running on the cloud platform so terraform apply will not perform any action, but i am not sure.
Appreciate if you help to clear my understanding please
Also another relevant point please what if a resource was changed manually from the cloud console for example and we tried to do any action from terraform on that resouces , what will happen ?

Thanks a lot ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some background from the documentation at https://www.terraform.io/intro/index.html

> Terraform generates an execution plan describing what it will do to reach the desired state, and then executes it to build the described infrastructure. As the configuration changes, Terraform is able to determine what changed and create incremental execution plans which can be applied.

The state mentioned gets saved when resources are modified. When you add a resource, it will get created and the state will be updated to reflect this. **The same is for removing of resources. When you remove a resource in Terraform by deleting the code or template file, the resource will be removed and state updated to to reflect the removed resource** (emphasis mine to illustrate the answer).

The second question of changing resources that drift from the state is a little more involved. When you create a plan against a resource that may have change, the provider will usually refresh the resources in state to compare them and show you what the changes to be made will be (ie. trying to change the resource to the declared state in the code).